# Values are not showing, and running into exceptions. What gives?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm making a savings worksheet for a project. It pulls values from a file and calculates the new total amount over a certain amount of periods with a Rate of Return and contributions every month. Debugging it works somewhat, but my values aren't showing up on the output section. Just running it (F5, I'm using Visual C++) throws an exception 0x76FE9862. I've been working on this for days with no real solutions, so any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Important note: File 'bucky' has these values:

```
4000

12

15

37
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

class savings {
    double balance, periods, ROI, values[4];
    string filename = "ROI.txt";
    ifstream bucky;
    char word[50];
    char graph[65];
    int count = 0;
    vector<double> cont;
    vector<double> saving;
    vector<double> total;
    double contr, save, tot;
    double findsum(vector<double> &vect, int period) {
        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < period; i++) {
            total += vect.at(i);
        }
        return total;
    }

    class stoc {
        bool dec = false;
        int dc = 0, count = 0;
        string holder;
    public:
        void flen() {
            while (dc < 2) {
                if (str[count] == 46)
                    dec = true;
                if (dec)
                    dc++;
                count++;
            }
            if (str[count + 1] > 4, str[count + 1] < 10) {
                str[count]++;
            }
            str.erase((count + 1), string::npos);


            lengt = str.length();
        }
        string str;
        int lengt;
    };
    stoc per, scont, ssave, ttot; //Reformatting these values to output as a graph
    double tcont, tsave;
    void addto(int count, stoc value) {
        graph[count] = value.str[count];
        cout << graph[count];
    }
    void makerow(int i) {
        cout << endl;
        per.str = to_string(i + 1) + ":";
        if (i == (periods + 1)) {
            per.str = "TOTALS:";
            cont.push_back(findsum(cont, periods));
            saving.push_back(findsum(saving, periods));
            total.push_back(total.at(i - 1));
        }
        scont.str = "$" + to_string(cont.at(i));
        ssave.str = "$" + to_string(saving.at(i));
        ttot.str = "$" + to_string(total.at(i));
        scont.flen();
        per.lengt = per.str.length();
        ssave.flen();
        ttot.flen();
        int limit[4] = { 0,14, 35, 53 }; //Marks when values start
        bool limon = false;
        int length[4] = { per.lengt, scont.lengt, ssave.lengt, ttot.lengt }; //How much space each value takes up
        int countlim, countlen, count;
        countlim = countlen = count = 0;
        countlen = -1;
        tcont = totals(cont);
        tsave = totals(saving);
        while (graph[count] != '\0') {
            for (countlim = 0; countlim < 4; countlim++) {
                if (count == limit[countlim]) {
                    limon = true;
                    countlen++;
                }
            }
            if (limon) {
                for (int x = 0; x < length[countlen]; x++) {
                    switch (countlen) {
                    case 0: addto(count, per);
                    case 1: addto(count, scont);
                    case 2: addto(count, ssave);
                    case 3: addto(count, ttot);
                    }
                }
                limon = false;
            }
            else {
                cout << " ";
            }
        } 
    }
    double totals(vector<double> value) {
        double total = findsum(value, periods);
        return total;
    }
public:
    void getinfo() {
        bucky.open(filename);
        if (!bucky.is_open()) 
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        while (bucky.good()) {
            bucky >> word;
            values[count] = atoi(word);
            count++;
        }
        balance = values[0];
        periods = values[1];
        ROI = values[2] / 100;
        contr = values[3];
    }
    void findans() {
        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
        cout << "Initial Balance: $" << balance << endl;
        cout << "Rate of Return: " << ROI * 100 << "%\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < (periods); i++) {
            //cout << "What are your contributions for period " << i + 1 << "?\n";
            //cin >> contr;
            cont.push_back(contr);
            if (i == 0) {
                //saving.push_back(save);
                save = ROI * (balance + cont.at(i));
                saving.push_back(save);
                //total.push_back(tot);
                tot = (balance + saving.at(i) + cont.at(i));
                total.push_back(tot);
            }
            else {
                //saving.push_back(save);
                save = ROI * (total.at(i - 1) + cont.at(i));
                saving.push_back(save);
                //total.push_back(tot);
                tot = total.at(i - 1) + cont.at(i) + saving.at(i);
                total.push_back(tot);
            }
            //cout << "Contributions for Period " << i + 1 << ": $" << cont.at(i) << endl;
            //cout << "Savings for Period " << i + 1 << ": $" << saving.at(i) << endl;
            //cout << "Total for Period " << i + 1 << ": $" << total.at(i) << endl;
            //cout << endl;
        }
        //cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
        //cout << "Total Contributions: $" << findsum(cont, periods) << endl;
        //cout << "Total Savings: $" << findsum(saving, periods) << endl;
        //cout << "Final Account Balance: $" << total.at(periods - 1) << endl;
    }
    void showgraph() {
        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
        cout << "-----------SAVINGS CALCULATOR----------\n";
        cout << "----Balance: $" << balance << endl;
        cout << "----Rate of Return: " << ROI * 100 << "%\n";
        cout << "PERIOD--------CONTRIBUTIONS--------SAVINGS-----------TOTAL\n";
        for (int f = 0; f < (periods+1); f++) {
            makerow(f);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    savings annual;
    savings *a = &annual;
    annual.getinfo();
    annual.findans();
    annual.showgraph();


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is `values` declared as array instead of `vector<double>`?

Comment: You need to be more consistent:  std::string for `word` and `graph`.  You already use `std::string` for `filename`.

Comment: See also `std::accumulate`, e.g. `const double sum = std::accumulate(&vect[0], &vect[period], 0.0);`

Comment: Your input loop is overly complicated and possibly misbehaving. Why aren't you just doing `bucky >> values[count]`?